# Advice on getting Push Notifications to Work on Production Builds

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

I have a production iOS App that I can send development push notifications (APNs) no problem from my production API environment.  The issue is when I archive the app and publish to the App Store the push notifications never work from the App downloaded from Itunes from my production API environment.

1. I have set up Certificate for APN distribution
2. I create the PEM file
   from the certificate.
3. APN are enabled in Xcode > Capabilities

In Apple's Document here "Troubleshooting Push Notifications"
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG21

> "When using Xcode to submit an app, Xcode will re-sign it using the
>   code signing identity and associated provisioning profile you select.
>   So the signature of the submitted app and its contents might be
>   different than what's in the Xcode archive."

Then

> Here's how to check the signature for an iOS app being submitted to
>   the App Store:

I follow the instructions but not sure what I should be looking for specifically when running this command?

```
codesign -d --entitlements :- "Payload/YourApp.app"
```

Also when I try and test this before submitting app by going to  Xcode > Window > Organizer and with the list of archives I will export the Itunes Production Archive by the following means:

```
Save for iOS App Store Deployment
Sign and Package application for distribution in the iOS App Store
```

I export the ipa file and will install via Itunes to my iphone.  However my production deployment build never completes installing on my iphone before being removed (Icon will show installing progress but then disappear)

So I'm not too sure how to test deployment push notifications (not development push notifications as that I can do) without submitting new build for review in Itunes Connect?

---

So what usually is the issue with Production Deployments not being able to send Push Notifications when development will work? (Same device identifier code, Same API environment etc)

How can I test deployment push notifications (not development) before submitting archive to Itune Connect?

Comment: You mentioned you setup the cert for push notifications but did you download and install that cert?  That happened to me once, I set it up on Apple's side but forgot to download and install it into Xcode on my side.

Comment: @fbara but certificates get applied on the server sending the push, non on Xcode, you are thinking of a profile not a certificate.

Comment: This doesn't make sense: "I have a production iOS App that I can send development push notifications (APNs) no problem from my production API environment".   What do you mean by a development push? You can either send pushes to a dev build via the Apple dev environment, or you can send pushes to a prod build via the Apple prod environment. Are you sure you are sending your pushes over the correct Apple environment?

Comment: "How can I test deployment push notifications (not development) before submitting archive to Itune Connect?" - Create a production build, install it via iTunes for example, set your server to send pushes over the Apple production environment and Not the development environment.

Comment: @SausageMachine thanks for responding!  What I mean is that with the Production Cert on my API server I can send a push notification to a build on my iphone (build from running xcode to my iphone; not the Itunes Production download)  and the push notification will work.  Basically something is not configured properly between when I run a build on my Xcode to Iphone versus Downloading the App from Itunes and pushing to my device.

Comment: @SausageMachine  When I create the production build and install the app via itunes it fails (the app icon will show with a progress indicator but then the app icon will disappear without installing the app)

Comment: Maybe your prod build isn't built correctly, difficult to say why, perhaps the distribution profile. But check out my answer and make sure you apply the rule of 3 first of all, which it seems you currently can't be, then as a separate issue get your prod build to install via iTunes (or similar, I like to use https://www.diawi.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason production pushes don't work while dev ones do is you have broken the

> "Push Rule of Three".

There are two sets of triplets:

```
a) Prod app - Prod gateway - Prod certificate
b) Dev app - Dev gateway - Dev certificate
```

You can't mix and match these together, if you have any combination that isn't either 3 Production things or 3 Dev things then the push won't work.
This is the "Push Rule of Three".

**Prod App/Dev App**

When you build/run via Xcode its a Dev app. When you
create an archive and make an ad-hoc distribution or publish to the
app store its a Prod app.

**Prod Gateway / Dev Gateway**

This is the prod gateway:

```
ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195
```

And this is the dev gateway:

```
ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
```

**Prod cert / Dev cert**

You need to use the Apple provisioning portal to generate a Dev cert and a Prod cert and sign your server with as appropriate (you can combine both the prod cert and prod key and dev cert and dev key into a single .pem file which makes it convenient to sign the server with both).

One other thing to bear in mind is that when creating the archive, in the Xcode code signing section, the provisioning profile must be set to a properly created distribution profile.

I think the best tutorial on Pushes is Ray Wenderlich's.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

This goes over the profile and the certificates and gets you to a position where something is working, however one huge omission of this tutorial is that it does not mention the Rule Of Three

In your situation, if you can send a push from your server to an Xcode build as indicated in your comments then it means two things:

1) You are using Apple's dev gateway. You MUST change that gateway to be able to send a push to a production build.

2) Your server has been signed with the development certificate. Your server MUST also be signed with the production certificate.

So you must have broken the rule of three, fix that and see if things work.

Comment: I broke the rule of 3.  When I saw the different URLs for APN for production versus sandbox I immediately went in looked at the command line tools I was using to test production pushes.  Sure enough I was sending the production pushes through the Sandbox and not Production URL..  I was PROD app > Dev Sandbox > Prod Cert   ... I'm using the Houston gem and just needed to add "-e production" to get it tor work.  Thanks!